# How to force a subclass to provide specific data within an overridden method

Tags: java, oop

I have a base class called `Feature`, and another two classes `Feature1` which is extension to the base class.
in other words, `Feature1` extends `Feature` as shown in the code.

what I want to do is, since `Feature1` extends the base `Feature` class it should override the `capture()` method, but what I want to do also is, 
to force `Feature1` also to provide a variable called `captureId` within the `capture()` method. which mean I want to force each feature extends `Feature` class must provide `captureId` within the overridden `capture()` method

**code**:

```
class Feature {
   ...
   public void capture() {

   }
}

class Feature1 extends Feature {
    ...
    @Override
    public void capture() {
        //captureId must be mandatory to be provided by each class extends Feature
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that is possible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm with @YasserHussain. Maybe if you explain your goal, we can find a better way to get there. By definition, the subclass is meant to provide its own implementation of the capture() function. That includes any variables defined within the scope of it. So there is no way to enforce that each implementation of the function contains a local variable with a certain name.

Comment: what is captureId? protected member field of base class?

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t make the `capture` method return a non-void value?

Comment: If you can make `Feature` abstract/an interface, you can force methods to be overridden/declared, but wouldn't be able to use it directly

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to say that you want `capture()` to return a Capture ID? If so, then you could require `capture()` to return a number, and leave it abstract so subclasses have to override it:

```
public class Feature
{
    public abstract int capture();
}
```

Do you just want to make sure that something happens to your Capture ID? An alternate way to do this would be to write a base method with your desired behavior, then have abstract methods that are called inside of it. For example:

```
public class Feature
{
    protected abstract int doSomethingWithCaptureId(int input);

    public void capture() {
        int captureId = this.doSomethingWithCaptureId(this.inputId);
        doSomeOtherTask();
    }
}

public class Feature1
{
    @Override
    protected int doSomethingWithCaptureId(int input) {
        // put your logic here
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is called [Template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)